# Is there a way to replace base path for a specific template in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js

I have two different projects. One has preview button which loads code from other project as an iFrame.
However some plugins cannot be found because the base path changes and I get 404 error. For example the request url is this in my **first project**:

> firstproject./_nuxt/example.js // returns 404

Normally in the **second project** the request url is this:

> secondproject./_nuxt/example.js  // returns 200

I want to change base path from my **second project** for only one template/page though. Like if this is the page I want, let's change my basepath from "firstproject" to "secondproject" so that nuxt can find the plugins and everything should work as it is expected. Is there a way to do this ?

edit: Or maybe I just need to put needed plugings in my first project is easier ?